# jQuery A problem while finding a child element

Tags: jquery

Hi I have that html snippet

```
<span class="container">
    <span class="inner">
       <span class="img_class">
           <img id=img1" />
       </span>
       <span class="strip"></span>
       <span class="abc_class"></span>
    </span>
</span>
```

when user clicks at the `<span class="abc_class"></span>`, I want to get the `closest` `<span class="img_class">` and then its `<img /.>`'s ID

To do so, I try

```
var myId = jQuery($(this).closest('.img_class')).find("img").attr("id");
```

where `$(this)` is that clicked  `<span class="abc_class">`

The `myId` is undefined. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) here, like this:

```
var myId = $(this).siblings('.img_class').find("img").attr("id");
```

For the *Why?* part: because there is no `.thumb-img` in your markup...also there's no need to re-wrap the result, you can just continue the chain.

Answer (score 0):

the **closest** jQuery function looks for the closest element matching the selector, but only among the ancestors of the current selection. cf [jquery.closest documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Thus you cannot use closest to find what looks like a sibling.

Nick's answer will certainly help you fix your problem.